# Is it possible to make Distribution.jl and StaticArrays.jl work together?

Tags: performance, julia

Because the involved dimensions are very small n<5 and for efficiency reasons I wanted to use [Distributions.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) with  [StaticArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) vectors & matrices.

However, I have the feeling that we can not use these packages together:

*ok with Julia "native" vector/matrix types:*

```
julia> MvNormal(zeros(3),reshape(Float64[2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2],3,3))
FullNormal(
dim: 3
μ: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Σ: [2.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 2.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 2.0]
)
```

*Error when called with StaticArrays.jl:*

```
julia> MvNormal(zeros(SVector{3}),SMatrix{3,3}(Float64[2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2]))
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching MvNormal(::SArray{Tuple{3},Float64,1,3}, ::SArray{Tuple{3,3},Float64,2,9})
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

**Question: is this true or is there a way to define distributions using StaticArrays.jl?**

Comment: I think this needs a PR to Distributions.jl to make work.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas That was my impression, I just wanted to be sure I didn't miss a trick. I will not do a PR because of my very specific needs. Thanks for the feedback (you can turn your comment into an answer if you wish, I will upvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for using StaticArrays and other types of `AbstractArray`s was added in Distributions.jl version 0.21.0 (in 2019).

As of today, both calls in the question work, and produce the same output.

```
julia> MvNormal(zeros(3),reshape(Float64[2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2],3,3))
FullNormal(
dim: 3
μ: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Σ: [2.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 2.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 2.0]
)


julia> MvNormal(zeros(SVector{3}),SMatrix{3,3}(Float64[2,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,2]))
MvNormal{Float64, PDMats.PDMat{Float64, SMatrix{3, 3, Float64, 9}}, SVector{3, Float64}}(
dim: 3
μ: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
Σ: [2.0 0.0 1.0; 0.0 2.0 0.0; 1.0 0.0 2.0]
)
```

Comment: It's not _exactly_ the same output..

Comment: Ah, I was looking just at the numbers, not the printed type name itself. But according to [the docs](https://juliastats.org/Distributions.jl/stable/multivariate/#Distributions.AbstractMvNormal), `FullNormal` is an alias for `MvNormal{Float64, PDMat{Float64,Matrix{Float64}},    Vector{Float64}}`, so the same type as the second one but with `Matrix` and `Vector` instead of their static equivalents.